# Functions, list and a square

Tags: python, list

The idea of this procedure is to convert a "square" (list of lists) and turn it around.
For example, by inputting the "square"

> [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

the procedure SHOULD return

> [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]

```
def turn_square(list4)
  n_index = [0,1,2]
  turned = []
  blank = []
  turned_i = 0
  for k in n_index:
    turned.append(blank)
  for i in n_index:
    for j in n_index:
      turned[turned_i].append(list4[j][i])
    turned_i = turned_i + 1
```

But, I don't know why, it is returning

> [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]]

Any ideas why? Please help.

Comment: If using builtins is Ok for this, you should look at zip.  (`zip(*square)`)

Comment: Two things to note: The thing you call a "square" is actually a matrix in math. The second thing: Have you thought about writting a matrix class instead of using lists with procedural programming?

Comment: ..and in matrix-math-language, "turn it around" is called "transpose".

Comment: There's no need to write a separate matrix class. The popular numpy package offers pre-written, high-performance classes for matrix and array datatypes. If you set this as a numpy array, then you can just use arrayname.T to transpose.

Answer (score 6):

```
zip(*square)
```

should work... that will transpose a 2d array

```
>>> square = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> zip(*square)
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

one caveat is that this creates a list of tuples... which makes them unmutable...but also faster

Answer (score 3):

I would use `zip` myself, but the fundamental problem in your code is here:

```
blank = []
[...]
for k in n_index:
    turned.append(blank)
```

You probably think this appends a new empty list, so that turned contains three empty lists.  But instead, it appends three references to the *same* empty list, so everything you do to one happens to "all" of them ("all" in quotes because there's really only one.)

```
>>> blank = []
>>> a = [blank, blank]
>>> a
[[], []]
>>> a[0].append("fred")
>>> a
[['fred'], ['fred']]
```

They're the same object in memory:

```
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
```

If we change your code so that it creates new lists [and add `return turned`], i.e.

```
    turned.append([])
```

then it works:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> x = turn_square(x)
>>> x
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> x = turn_square(x)
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

[I didn't do any other error testing, so it still might not be correct, but this explains the weird symptom you were seeing.]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be numerical data, and depending on your goals, the numpy array data type (and transpose operation) may be what you want. That will improve performance, which can be important for large datasets.

But if you absolutely must have this as a python list (such as if the lists contain a mix of text and numeric data) and if the tuple solution above doesn't meet your needs (such as if you need to do further manipulations to edit the results in place later), you can try a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

>>> [ [ j[i] for j in data ] for i in range( len(j) ) ]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```